# How to use delimiters to ignore floats greater than 1?

Tags: java, delimiter

So I'm reading in a two column data txt file of the following from:

20 0.15

30 0.10

40 0.05

50 0.20

60 0.10

70 0.10

80 0.30

and I want to put the second column into an array( {0.15,0.10,0.05,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.3}) but I don't know how to parse the floats that are greater than 1. I've tried to read the file in as scanner and use delimiters but I don't know how to get ride of the integer that proceeds the token. Please help me.

here is my code for reference:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class OneStandard {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File("ClaimProportion.txt"));//reads in claim dataset txt file

        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File("ClaimProportion.txt"));

        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(new File("ClaimProportion.txt"));


        //this while loop counts the number of lines in the file
        while (input1.hasNextLine()) {
            NumClaim++;
            input1.nextLine();
        }
            System.out.println("There are "+NumClaim+" different claim sizes in this dataset.");
            int[] ClaimSize = new int[NumClaim];

            System.out.println("      ");
            System.out.println("The different Claim sizes are:");

            //This for loop put the first column into an array
        for (int i=0; i<NumClaim;i++){
            ClaimSize[i] = input2.nextInt();
            System.out.println(ClaimSize[i]);
            input2.nextLine();
        }


        double[] ProportionSize = new double[NumClaim];
        //this for loop is trying to put the second column into an array
        for(int j=0; j<NumClaim; j++){
            input3.skip("20");
            ProportionSize[j] = input3.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(ProportionSize[j]);
            input3.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example on this part  that you said `I don't know how to get rid of the integer that proceeds the token`

Answer (score 5):

You can use "YourString".split("regex");
Example:

```
String input = "20 0.15";

String[] items = input.split(" "); // split the string whose delimiter is a " "

float floatNum = Float.parseFloat(items[1]); // get the float column and parse

if (floatNum > 1){
    // number is greater than 1
} else {
    // number is less than 1
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `Scanner`. If you know that each line always contains one `int` and one `double`, you can read the numbers directly instead of reading lines.

You also don't need to read the file once to get the number of lines, again to get the numbers etc. - you can do it in one go. If you use `ArrayList` instead of array, you won't have to specify the size - it will grow as needed.

```
List<Integer> claimSizes = new ArrayList<>();
List<Double> proportionSizes = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNext()) {

    claimSizes.add(scanner.nextInt());
    proportionSizes.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
```

Now number of lines is `claimSizes.size()` (also `proportionSizes.size()`). The elements are accessed by `claimSizes.get(i)` etc.